# how to run a multiple instance of a jar on a linux server?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, performance

I would like to know how things work when we run a multiple instances of a java program (jar) memory allocation, heap space, etc.  Is it like creating multiple object of a class? If we want to have common accessible memory(which can be accessed the instances of the same jar) during their course of action, what is the best way of doing it? (something like static variables - common memory for all the instances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Linux server multiple instances of `java -cp libname.jar <class>` or `java -jar libname.jar` are just another processes not sharing (implicitly) anything, well protected from one other. So generally running multiple applications of the same kind (each in own JVM) is like running multiple instances of the text editor. Of cause if your app opens ports, writes files, and does other things which may not well be shareable, then special steps (like assigning each instance different port to listen or implementing file locks) may be required.

If your question is rather about loading two jar files into a single JVM instance then the answer lays in the scope of multiple (possibly hierarchically related) [`classloaders`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) and result highly depends on the topology of classloaders used.